# Random weird 403 redirects on my site homepage?

Tags: .htaccess

Not sure how to fix this or replicate the error but it seems that sometimes my site goes into a 403 redirect error.

I've deleted cookies on my personal browser but it seems to enter 403 on other machines (on different IP's)

My hunch could be the htaccess file....

Can anyone spot anything odd with the following rules?

thanks....

```
<files .htaccess>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#Options -Indexes 

# All pages www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# below to force https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.my-site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Did you find out what it was buddy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what it was - basically my DNS was set differently...I was using OpenDNS and it was messing up my personal UI experience...